# How to increase font size in PDF generated by phpmyadmin "export as pdf"?

Tags: phpmyadmin, export-to-pdf

I have searched in [PhpMyAdmin Configuration documentation](https://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/config.html#pdf-options) but couldnt come up with anything useful. In general how to customize the output of pdf export by phpmyadmin?

Comment: Are you talking about schema export or data export?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no such setting to control the font size of the generated pdfs. You might be able to achieve this by tweaking the code.

Comment: yaa.. how to do that? Can you suggest file paths where i might start looking ?

Comment: If you are using version 4.0.x of phpMyAdmin, look into libraries/plugins/export/PMA_ExportPdf.class.php for data export or libraries/schema/Pdf_Relation_Schema.class.php for schema export

Answer (score 0):

A little late but i think it may help someone someday

Export the table into word document then edit the word document in your word processor eg Microsoft Word then edit the font and other details here.